# NGINX HTTPs redirect not working for subdomains

Tags: nginx, ssl, server, dns, subdomain

I am using the following NGINX configuration to redirect **all** wildcard subdomains to https:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name "~^(?<sub>.+)\.example\.com$";
        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

It works on certain browsers Chrome, but not through some VPN platforms.

The website error returned is:

```
The requested URL was not recognised as a valid URL. Attempted to load: https://~^(?<sub>.+)\.example\.com$/
```

I have also tried using the following as the `server_name`:

```
server_name ~^.*$
```

But it returns the error:

The website error returned is:

```
The requested URL was not recognised as a valid URL. Attempted to load: ~^.*$
```

How could I get NGINX to redirect HTTP to HTTPS?

I have another site in Apache which redirects just fine across all platforms, so cannot be an issue with the online VPN services themselves.

Comment: You cannot use the `$server_name` variable in the `return` statement. Use `$host` instead.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks, that works. I'm also using `$server_name` for the root domain name redirect and that works for some reason too - not sure why

Comment: The value of `$server_name` represents the value of the `server_name` directive. You were using a regular expression which does not provide a good value for `$server_name`.